Android flow cancelled and not restarted
Problem: stateFlow not restarts if cancelled after resubscribing on it.
I have ViewPager2 in which I show ListFragments. Each fragment has ListFragmentViewModel provide data soruce for recycler view with pagination:
    val itemList: StateFlow<PagingData<RecyclerViewData>> =
            searchQueryFlow
                .flatMapLatest { searchData ->
                    repo.search(searchData)
                }
                .map {
                    it.map { loadCarriers -> mapLoadCarriersToViewData(loadCarriers) }
                }
                .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
                .onCompletion {
                    if (it is CancellationException) {
                        Log.d("Test", "CancellationException")
                    }
                }
                .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), PagingData.empty())

Fragment code:
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                    viewModel.itemList.collectLatest { list ->
                        adapter.submitData(list)
                    }
                }
            }

        }

This fragment is #2 in ViewPager. If I open this fragment directly, everything works fine. But if I open fragment #4, current one created, started, but not showed, so flow are cancelled (I receive "CancellationException"). If then I open this fragment, it once again subscribe to collectLatest from my flow, but it's no longer works.
How could I fix this?

A StateFlow doesn’t get cancelled directly, but would get cancelled if the viewModelScope you passed to stateIn got cancelled. But that only gets cancelled when the ViewModel is going away, as long as you aren’t manually cancelling it for some reason. Are these two fragments using a shared viewmodel instance?
